# gif анимация на php

Tags: анимация, php

Задался вопросом создания анимированной gif картинки, средствами PHP, но информации в интернете по этому поводу я не нашёл. Существует ли какая-нибудь библиотека для работы с ними?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть, не подскажу точно, но на хабре есть статья называется [капча 4д](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/crazydev/82771/). Там полностью описывается как рисовать гифы. Если не ошибаюсь используется библиотека Imagick.

Спасибо Sh4dow за то что нашел статью

Comment: <a href="http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/crazydev/82771/">А вот и она</a>

Как вариант для отморозков/задротов/извращенцев - курить формат гиф и ручками писать класс)

Comment: Да да) я пробовал ее реализовать) Не очень получилось) Возможно еще пробовать буду)

Comment: Буду курить отсюда: http://el-izdanie.narod.ru/gl4/4-1.htm
Будет прогресс, напишу.

Comment: Ого, уважуха) Удачи)

Answer (score 2):

[Создание анимированных GIF на PHP](http://mezon.org/items/8.htm) с помощью GIFEncoder.class